# Android Hiding ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to hide my action bar. Please check on my codes. It doesnt seems to work. I've also list out my LOGCAT at the bottom of my codes. Please help.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

            Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                                .setText("Android")
                                .setTabListener(new AndroidFragment())
                                .setIcon(R.drawable.android);

            actionBar.addTab(tab);

            tab = actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText("Apple")
                    .setTabListener(new AppleFragment())
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.apple);

            actionBar.addTab(tab);


        }  

    }
```

LOGCAT :

```
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab/in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
10-06 18:17:25.781: E/AndroidRuntime(15962):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: If you are trying to hide the actionbar why not just call  actionBar.hide(); ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` the `ActionBar` object you read three lines later is null. Thus the NPE.

But why do you hide the ActionBar in this way *and* then get the object and set tabs and whatnot to an invisible ActionBar?

See also Andrei's comment to your question.